# How to add a Stat whenever player 1 makes the ball and then player 2 touches it using Server Sided Scripts

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

so i've been trying to add a stat using server sided scripts. so player 1 throws the ball and the player 2 touches the ball then player 1 gets that stat?

```
function onTouched(hit)
    if not hit or not hit.Parent then return end 
    local now = r.Stepped:Wait()
    if (now - last_sound_time > .1) then
        Ball.fart:Play()
        last_sound_time = now
    else
        return
    end

    local humanoid = hit.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
    local tag = Ball:FindFirstChild("creator")
    if tag and humanoid then
        if not IsTeamMate(tag.Value,game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(humanoid.Parent)) then
            tagHumanoid(humanoid)       
            --humanoid:TakeDamage(damage)
            game.ReplicatedStorage.remoteService.playDamage:FireAllClients()
            game.ReplicatedStorage.remoteService.yellowPoop:FireAllClients()
            if connection then connection:Disconnect() end
        end
        humanoid.PlatformStand = true
        --game:GetService("ServerStorage").yellow.yellowValue.Value = "itWASallYELLOW123098"
        --print(game:GetService("ServerStorage").yellow.yellowValue.Value)
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.pooped.Value += 1
        game.ReplicatedStorage.remoteService.yellowPoop:FireAllClients()
        wait(1)
        humanoid.PlatformStand = false
        --game:GetService("ServerStorage").yellow.yellowValue.Value = "none"
        --print(game:GetService("ServerStorage").yellow.yellowValue.Value)
    else
    end
end
```

i expected the change to change when player1's ball touches it but it seems like localplayer is only accessed using localscripts but then the platform stand just keeps me there with no stat at all